# Why the IS NOT NULL statement is returning everything

Tags: mysql, sql

I am adapting an existing query to only pick those records where the guidelineschecked field has a date in it. When I try adding in u.guidelineschecked IS NOT NULL, it still returns all the records.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.email, u.guidelineschecked
FROM transcriber t
     JOIN user u
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT tid FROM workertypeidlist WHERE workertypeid = 3)
  AND t.suspended = 0
  AND u.guidelineschecked IS NOT NULL;
```

I changed the query to:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.email, u.guidelineschecked
FROM transcriber t
     JOIN user u ON (t.id = u.transcriberid AND u.guidelineschecked IS NOT NULL)
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT tid FROM workertypeidlist WHERE workertypeid = 3)
AND t.suspended = 0;
```

And that returns less records, but there are still some records that contain a null value in the guidelineschecked field.

I would assume that the IS NOT NULL would exclude any fields with a null value. I am very new to mySQL, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: Here is an image of the results from the console query. I want only the records that have dates in them.

[image: database results]

Comment: OK, my mySQL is a little rusty, however, in the second query, sure you said dont join it if guidelineschecked is not null, but for all the records that didnt join they are still in your list.  I believe both queries suffer as the first doesnt join u on anything specific so could possibly have done all lines in t link to all lines in u..

While Im sure mySQL supports left, right, inner and outer joins, you probably could just get away with that second query and move the "and u.guidelineschecked is not null" to the where clause after t.suspended = 0, and you should get what you wanted.

Comment: Are you certain the values are `null` and not e.g. `''` (the empty string)? What is the datatype of `guidelinechecked`?

Comment: I am a little confused as to the kind of join to use. I want all the records in transcriber that have guidelineschecked in the user table. Can you help me on that point?

Comment: Your first join misses ON clause, so you're doing a cross join.

Comment: @Solarflare, the datatype of the guidelineschecked is datetime.

Comment: Can we see sample data and expected results please? Note that NULL is a specific status. It's not the same as just "contains an empty string, or a space, or other hidden character".

Comment: Coloring something over with transparent color doesn't really hide the underlying text. :D

Comment: Didn't think it would come out as transparent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with someone else, we discovered that the field is actually filled with zeroes, but displays as null. I have no idea why this is happening and neither does my boss, but we solved the problem like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.email, u.guidelineschecked
FROM transcriber t
     JOIN user u ON u.transcriberid = t.id
     JOIN (
SELECT tid FROM
    workertypeidlist
WHERE workertypeid = 3
) t2 on t.id = t2.tid
WHERE u.guidelineschecked > '2001-01-01';
```

Thank you to everyone who commented. I appreciate your time and wisdom.